# Why is gatsby-plugin-image missing image prop?

Tags: react-native, gatsby, netlify, gatsby-image

*Editor Note: This question may not be helpful to most people searching the `[gatsby-plugin-image] Missing image prop` error. The author answered his own question below at
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69313485/1120027*

---

I am working on improving my image sizes and noticed that gatsby image was deprecated so I decided to try on the `gatsby-plugin-image`. On static images like this:

```
<StaticImage
  src="../images/image.png"
  alt="software design"
  layout={'fullWidth'}
  formats={['auto', 'webp']}
/>
```

is working fine. But when working on the images from netlify cms I get that following error `Missing image prop` even I have following:

```
<GatsbyImage
  image={refImage}
  alt={refImage}
  layout={'fullWidth'}
  formats={['auto', 'webp']}
/>
```

The whole file is as follows.

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { GatsbyImage, getImage } from 'gatsby-plugin-image'

import * as S from './styled'
import './postitem.css'

const ReferenceItem = ({
  slug,
  background,
  category,
  date,
  title,
  description,
  image,
  timeToRead,
}) => {
  const refImage = getImage(image)
  return (
    <S.BlogColumn>
      <article className="post" key={slug}>
        <S.BlogColumn>
          {image && (
            <GatsbyImage
              image={refImage}
              alt={refImage}
              layout={'fullWidth'}
              formats={['auto', 'webp']}
            />
            /* <img
                 style={{
                   display: 'block',
                   width: '100%',
                   height: 'auto',
                 }}
                 src={`/${image}`}
                 alt={image}
            /> */
          )}
          {!image && (
            <img
              style={{
                display: 'block',
                width: '100%',
                height: 'auto',
              }}
              src={require('../../../static/assets/img/cover.webp')}
              alt="cover"
            />
          )}
        </S.BlogColumn>
        <S.BlogColumn>
          <div className="post-content">
            <h2 className="post-title">{title}</h2>
            <p className="post-item-description">{description}</p>
            <span className="post-date">
              {date}&nbsp;&nbsp;—&nbsp;
            </span>
            <span className="post-words">
              {timeToRead} minute read
            </span>
          </div>
        </S.BlogColumn>
      </article>
    </S.BlogColumn>
  )
}

ReferenceItem.propTypes = {
  slug: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  background: PropTypes.string,
  category: PropTypes.string,
  date: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  timeToRead: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  description: PropTypes.string,
}

export default ReferenceItem
```

Comment: Well, this should be the problem: `const imgName = image ? image.split('/')[3] : false`, more specifically the `[3]` part. Get the last element in the array, don't hard code an index(which I guess should be 4 in your specific case anyway).

Comment: @zhulien I tried removing that `[3]` and it gives me following error `Cannot read property 'fluid' of null`

Comment: I am trying to add child image sharp to the image.

Answer (score 0):

The `image` needs to be of type GatsbyImageData as processed by `gatsby-plugin-sharp` or another source plugin that generates the correct format.

Additionally, the props you're passing to `GatsbyImage` will not work. `StaticImage` takes props, `GatsbyImage` needs that information to be passed to the sharp query that generates the images. For example,

```
{
   image {
     childImageSharp {
         gatsbyImageData(layout: FULL_WIDTH)
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: What I understood from the documentation is that static one doesnt take props on the src but dynamic one does

Comment: It's the opposite. The StaticImage component takes props and GatsbyImage does not, opting to pass those options to the resolver itself. If you can point to where in the docs you found this confusing I'd love to change it.

Comment: I just can't get that to work with allmarkdown remark

Answer (score 0):

They both can take props but Static Image can't get passed props from another component. No passing down to static image. The documentation for the plugin lists which props are for both, and which aren't.

The one that can take the passing down props is Dynamic one, GatsbyImage.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that problem was react native version `0.65` where the `headerTransparent: true makes the button not work properly in android device. And is fixed in the next version.